# React not loading, It also doesn't recognize document commands

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

Extremely simple `HTML` and `javascript` set up for `React.js` not working. I followed exactly the instructions on the react website but it is not working. I would appreciate if anyone can see any error.

Below is the `HTML` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="file1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Even the `document.getElementById` command is not working as shown in the error message on the screenshot below:
[image: error]

Windows 10 32bit, Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You're running this using node this needs to be run by the browser

Comment: At the console at the browser I get this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at file1.js:2:10

Comment: Sounds like a correct error message now. Indeed, e is not defined

Comment: yeah but the React documentation mentions it... https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: It doesn't say that you can use NodeJS to run it though. Just open the HTML file in a browser. There is no `document` in NodeJS.

Comment: Thank you , this might be the answer, but How can I remove node from the output of vsc?

Comment: You created a `index.html` file, so you can open that in the browser. The best way to do it is by right-clicking it in VS CODE and selecting "open with live server". If you don't have that command, you can install it under "extensions" and then search for "live server".

Comment: Your comments solved the problem, there is a problem with the documentation of react , because it mentions an "e" that is not defined.. I liked all comments that helped, as the above  comments solved the problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I hope this finds you well.

You better use any of the NPM react app creating commands, to create your react app. Like npx create-react-app and it will then have the NPM modules that require you to get that root ID you are trying to get using vanilla/backbone js document.getelementbyid while that is not how the root is called. Using the boiler plate that NPM gives you, you can import react and reactdom then to manipulate that single HTML that react renders to the client.

I hope this is the answer to your question.